# Regex to avoid splitting on special characters

Tags: java, regex

I am having requirement on splitting a string on keywords like `AND,OR,NOT,&,|,!,(,).`

There are special condition where I don't want to split words if any paraenthesis `'(' or ')'` comes in the middle of the word or parenthesis with special characters comes in the middle of the word.Neither I want to split on any special characters .Also I don't want to split on spaces.

If parenthesis comes at the start of the word or end of the word then only  I have to split.

For Example :

My logic is as below.

```
String str = "(((Tom AND Jerray) AND Mic(#*ey and miney)) ";

str = str.replaceAll("\\s*\\(\\s*", "(");

str = str.replaceAll("\\s*\\)\\s*", ")");

str = str.replaceAll("and\\(", " and (");

str = str.replaceAll("\\)and", ") and ");

String[] splitArray= str.toUpperCase().split(("((?<=\\bOR\\b|\\bAND\\b|\\bNOT\\b)|(?=\\bOR\\b|\\bAND\\b|\\bNOT\\b))|((?<=(^| )\\(+)+\\b+)|(\\b(?=\\)($| )))"));
```

Splitted Output what I am getting from splitArray is :

```
(((

TOM

AND

JERRAY)

AND

MIC(#*EY

AND,

MINEY))
```

***But I want the output as :***

```
(((

TOM

AND

JERRAY

**)**

AND

MIC(#*EY

AND,

MINEY

**))**
```

Code I had written is not splitting closed parenthesis.I want to split that too. Can Anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "(((Tom AND Jerray) AND Mic(#*ey and miney)) ";

String[] splitArray= str.toUpperCase().split(("AND|OR|(\\()+\\(|\\)(\\s|\\))+|\\)^(.)|^(.)\\("));
```

Comment: But this Regex is not retaining splitters. Is there any way to retain that ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Modified the pattern to split over `and`, instead of spaces.

Are you looking for this?

```
String str = "(((Tom AND Jerray) AND Mic(#*ey and miney)) ";
String[] splitArray= str.toUpperCase().split("(?i)(?<=\\()()(?=\\w)|(?<=\\w+)()(?=\\))|()(?=and)|(?<=and)()");
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The regex above is getting splitted over space also. I don't want to split it over space. Can you avoid splitting it on space ?

Comment: That's conflicting from your desired output in the post.If you don't want to split it over space, the output in the post is not right. It would be: `(((`, `TOM AND JERRAY`, `) AND MIC(#*EY AND MINEY`, and `))`.

Comment: Hey Hi, Thanks for your prompt reply.
But if you read my question properly, on the first line I had mentioned my requirements to split over, and also I had mentioned after few lines that I don't want to split it over space.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I just edited the pattern. Hope it works for you.